# Disabling mouseEvents after gameOver

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a game project that I am trying to disable any mouse interactions on it after the game has ended and only to re-enable it after i restart my game.

I tried using a condition with the in-game timer such that it enables the mouseEvent function only when the timer is above 0s.

```
if (startTime > 0) {
    setupMouseInteraction();
  }
```

However I am still able to interact with the game despite the timer running out.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. This isn't enough code to be able to assist with.

Comment: mouseEvents are captured in your main file using functions like `mouseClicked`, `mouseMoved()`.  Just add a condition inside this functions, so they only do something if that condition evaluates true. Example. `if (!gameOver) { // do stuff}` or you could also do `if (gameOver) {return; }`